# Struts tag: multiple pagers in one jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I've one jsp that include other JSPs.

Main jsp:

```
        <% java.util.ArrayList <String> subJspName = (java.util.ArrayList <String>)(request.getSession().getAttribute("subJspName"));
        for (int jspIdx=0; jspIdx<subJspName.size(); jspIdx++) 
        {%>
            <jsp:include page='<%= subJspName.get(jspIdx) %>' />
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        <%} %>
```

Others sub JSPs:

```
<layout:pager maxPageItems="5" width="100%"
                                sessionPagerId="currentPageZERO"> <!-- in the second sub-JSP, it will be currentPageONE -->
                                <logic:notEmpty
                                    name="tabellaGenericaForm"
                                    property="listaLogAccordoVec[0]"> <!-- in the second sub-JSP, it will be listaLogAccordoVec[1] -->
                                    <layout:collection
                                        name="tabellaGenericaForm"
                                        property="listaLogAccordoVec[0]" id="elemento"
                                        width="100%" styleClass="LISTA" styleClass2="LISTA2">

                                        <layout:collectionItem title="form.useragg"
                                            property="useragg" sortable="true" width="10%">
                                            <bean:write name="elemento" property="useragg" />
                                        </layout:collectionItem>                                         
                                    </layout:collection>


                </logic:notEmpty>
            </layout:pager>
```

When I show only a single sub JSP, the pager works fine (if I click to the second page button, it works) for all the sub-JSP.
When I show more sub JSP on the same page, the only pager that works is the pager of the first sub JSP (the jsp on the top), and when I click for example on the button page 2 of the first sub-jsp, all the sub JSP go to page 2 (instead of only the first sub-jsp).

How I fix this?
[image: SCREENSHOT]

Here the html generated (I cleaned it a little, so it's more readable and left only the part relative to the three tables):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#eaf3fa" colspan="8" class="testoGrassetto2"
            style="text-align: center">Dati anagrafici dello straniero</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">


            <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="CENTER"
                    width="100%" class="LISTA">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
                                border="0" width="100%">

                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=useragg&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>User agg.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=dataagg&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Data agg.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=operazione&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Operaz.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=codicefiscale&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Codice fiscale</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=cognome&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Cognome</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=nome&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Nome</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=sesso&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Sesso</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=statocivile&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Stato civile</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=datanascita&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Data di nascita</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=descrizionenazionenascita&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Nazione di nascita</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=descittanascita&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Città di nascita</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=descrizionecittadinanza&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Cittadinanza di nascita</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=idrichiestaali&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>ID richiesta ALI</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=utenteali&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Utente ALI</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="25%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=passwordali&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Password ALI</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>

                                <!-- HERE THERE'S THE DATAS, I HIDE THEM -->

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%"
                id="pager1380269837677">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" style="text-align: right"></td>
                    <td>1&nbsp;<a
                        href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=&amp;layoutCollectionState=0&pagerPage=1&pagerSessionId=currentPageZERO">2</a>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="50%" style="text-align: left"><a
                        href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=0&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=&amp;layoutCollectionState=0&pagerPage=1&pagerSessionId=currentPageZERO">&gt;&gt;</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
    </tr>

</body>
</html>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>








<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#eaf3fa" colspan="8" class="testoGrassetto2"
            style="text-align: center">Dati di recapito</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">


            <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="CENTER"
                    width="100%" class="LISTA">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
                                border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=useragg&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>User agg.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=dataagg&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Data agg.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=operazione&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Operaz.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=comuneresidenza&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Comune di residenza</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=desprovinciaresidenza&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Provincia di residenza</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=indirizzoresidenza&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Indirizzo di residenza</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=numerocivicoresidenza&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Civico di residenza</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=capresidenza&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>CAP</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=telefono&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Telefono</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=email&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Email</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>

                                <!-- HERE THERE'S THE DATAS, I HIDE THEM -->

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%"
                id="pager1380269837836">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" style="text-align: right"></td>
                    <td>1&nbsp;<a
                        href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=&amp;layoutCollectionState=0&pagerPage=1&pagerSessionId=currentPageONE">2</a>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="50%" style="text-align: left"><a
                        href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=1&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=&amp;layoutCollectionState=0&pagerPage=1&pagerSessionId=currentPageONE">&gt;&gt;</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
    </tr>

</body>
</html>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>








<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>

    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#eaf3fa" colspan="8" class="testoGrassetto2"
            style="text-align: center">Dati dei documenti e del permesso di
            soggiorno</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">


            <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="CENTER"
                    width="100%" class="LISTA">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
                                border="0" width="100%">

                                <tr valign="top">
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=useragg&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>User agg.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=dataagg&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Data agg.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=operazione&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Operaz.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=destipodocumento&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Tipo documento</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=numerodocumento&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Numero documento</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=rilasciatoda&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Rilasciato da</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=datarilasciodocumento&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Data rilascio</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=datascadenzadocumento&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>data scadenza</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=duratapermessosoggiorno&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Durata permesso di soggiorno</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="15%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=tiporichiestapermessosoggiorno&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Tipo richiesta permesso di soggiorno</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="LISTA" width="10%"><table border="0"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a
                                                    href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=desprovinciaprefpermesso&amp;layoutCollectionState=0"><img
                                                        src="/AccordoIntegrazione/config/sort.gif" border="0"
                                                        alt="sort">
                                                </a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>Provincia pref. permesso</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>

                                <!-- HERE THERE'S THE DATAS, I HIDE THEM -->

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%"
                id="pager1380269837911">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%" style="text-align: right"></td>
                    <td>1&nbsp;<a
                        href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=&amp;layoutCollectionState=0&pagerPage=1&pagerSessionId=currentPageTWO">2</a>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="50%" style="text-align: left"><a
                        href="/AccordoIntegrazione/sort.do?layoutCollection=2&amp;layoutCollectionProperty=&amp;layoutCollectionState=0&pagerPage=1&pagerSessionId=currentPageTWO">&gt;&gt;</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
    </tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<% java.util.ArrayList <String> subJspName = (java.util.ArrayList <String>)(request.getSession().getAttribute("subJspName"));
int i=0;
for (int jspIdx=0; jspIdx<subJspName.size(); jspIdx++)
{%>
  <jsp:include page='<%= subJspName.get(i) %>' />
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
<%
i =  i + 1;
} %>
```

Comment: but it's the same like me. You just changed a variable name.
The code works fine for showing the sub-jsp. The problem is only when I click on the other page of the sub-jsp that are paginated

Comment: I insert a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use struts1, but from the normal googling, javascript knowledge & looking at your code and , I think this should work :

```
<layout:collection
                                        name="tabellaGenericaForm"
                                        property="listaLogAccordoVec[0]" id="elemento"
                                        width="100%" styleClass="LISTA" styleClass2="LISTA2">
```

I guess the above code is responsible for displaying the paging elements (1,2 prev, next) I see there's an id field/attribute of this tag.

Just use different values for the id tag in different sub jsps and it should work fine.

Comment: I tried to rename elemento to elemento0 in the first jsp, elemento to elemento1 in the next, and so on. But didn't work. Nothing changed.

Comment: please add generated html to the question.

Comment: I added it to the first post.

Comment: you noticed - all paginated links are same ?

Comment: No. The first end with: pagerSessionId=currentPageZERO 
The second with: pagerSessionId=currentPageONE, and so on

Comment: sorry I just missed that. Anyways, it's not java-script issue which I was thinking it is. They are perfect links and hence, each & every link should work even though don't know why clicking the first one changes the other two also.